# Get ddSlick selected items to dynamically add to default total on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the value of the selected dropdown menu items to dynamically add to the total which is in a text input field with the id="result" when/as an item is selected.

I am using the [ddSlick](http://designwithpc.com/plugins/ddslick) library.

The value from id="basic" (below) is the base value of the total before choosing any options (the selected items in the drop down menus x 5 menus).

```
<input id="basic" type="radio" name="basic" value="850.00" checked="checked" class="hide">
```

The code for the item before it is selected:

```
<div id="arms" class="dd-container">
    <div class="dd-select">
        <input class="dd-selected-value" type="hidden">
</div>
```

The code for the item once it is selected (gets added dynamically on selection):

```
<div id="arms" class="dd-container">
    <div class="dd-select">
        <input class="dd-selected-value" type="hidden" value="150.00|2" name="arm">
</div>
```

The selected items from 2 more of the drop down menus:

```
<div id="mechanism" class="dd-container">
    <input class="dd-selected-value" type="hidden" value="0.00|18" name="mechanism">
</div>

<div id="fabric" class="dd-container">
    <input class="dd-selected-value" type="hidden" value="0.00|185" name="fabric">
</div>
```

All the values of the items are formatted with the price value separated by | followed by the product ID: value="price|ID"

This is the id="result" input text field I want to add the values from the selected items to:

```
<div class="totalHead">Total price: R<input type="text" name="total" id="result" class="result right">.00 </div>
```

The jQuery code for each dropdown menu (I am usind WordPress therefore the jQuery() value):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $('#arms').ddslick({
            data:armData,
            width:380,
            selectText: "Select your arm rest",
            onSelected: function (data) {
        $('#arms .dd-selected-value').prop('name', 'arm');
        var arms = $("#arms .dd-selected-value").val().split('|');
            }
        });
    $('#mechanism').ddslick({
            data:mechData,
            width:380,
            selectText: "Select your mechanism",
            onSelected: function (data) {
        $('#mechanism .dd-selected-value').prop ('name', 'mechanism');
        var mechanism = jQuery("#mechanism .dd-selected-value").val().split('|');
            }
        });
    $('#base').ddslick({
            data:baseData,
            width:380,
            selectText: "Select your base",
            onSelected: function (data) {
        $('#base .dd-selected-value').prop ('name', 'base');
        var base = jQuery("#base .dd-selected-value").val().split('|');
            }
        });
    $('#myDropdown').ddslick({
            data:fabricData,
            width:380,
            selectText: "Select your fabric (or Back rest)",
            onSelected: function (data) {
        $('#myDropdown .dd-selected-value').prop ('name', 'fabric');
        var fabric = jQuery("#myDropdown .dd-selected-value").val().split('|');
            }
        });
        $('#myBaseDropdown').ddslick({
            data:fabricData,
            width:380,
            selectText: "Select your base fabric",
            onSelected: function (data) {
                //console.log(data);
        $('#myBaseDropdown .dd-selected-value').prop ('name', 'fabricBase');
        var fabricBase = jQuery("#myBaseDropdown .dd-selected-value").val().split('|');
            }
        });
     });
```

This is the code I have developed to get the values when the items are selected and total up the values:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('#arms .dd-selected-value', '#mechanism .dd-selected-value', '#base .dd-selected-value', '#myDropdown .dd-selected-value', '#myBaseDropdown .dd-selected-value', '[name="quantity"]').on('change', function(){

    var basic = jQuery("#basic").val();
    var quantity = jQuery("[name='quantity']");

    if("#arms .dd-selected-value".length > 0){
        var b = parseInt(basic[0], 10);
        var a = parseInt(arms[0], 10);
        var m = parseInt(mechanism[0], 10);
        var bs = parseInt(base[0], 10);
        var f = parseInt(fabric[0], 10);
        var fb = parseInt(fabricBase[0], 10);
        var q = parseInt(quantity.val(), 10);
        jQuery("#result").val((b + a + m + bs + f + fb) * q);
    }
    });

jQuery('#arms .dd-selected-value', '#mechanism .dd-selected-value', '#base .dd-selected-value', '#myDropdown .dd-selected-value', '#myBaseDropdown .dd-selected-value', '[name="quantity"]').trigger('change', function () {
});
```

I have the default value jQuery("#basic").val(); displaying on page load, but cannot get the selected items to add to the default total.

Can anyone please help show me why this is not working?

Also, because the 'dd-selected-value' input field has no value until the item is selected, is the .on('change') event relevant? If not what should I use to capture the "selected" action?